# Behavior of recreated tables in sync

Tags: silverlight, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

In Synchronization, if I delete a table from database(not deleting its tracking table) and recreate it with same properties and datatypes, Its not syncing changes that I make in new created table.

```
What is the problem that prevent syncing my changes?

And what should I do If I cant de-provisioned the whole scope and have to make changes in database table?
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dropped the tables, you would have dropped the triggers for change tracking that updates the tracking tables when changes are made.

Comment: it means I have to re-create the scope, and add table again to continue sync work??